# How to cancel() timer after opening the Activity for the second time?

Tags: android, timer

Greeting,

I created timer to show toast for a specific time. The timer will work after switch on the switch key and it will be canceled once switch off the switch key. I'm using SharedPrefrences to save the state of switch view. Everything is working fine, however once I go back to previous Activity and open the Activity again then try to cancel the timer by switch off the switch key I got force close message. So, what is your suggestions to solve this problem?

The Code:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AutoReminder extends Activity {

    TimerTask tt;
    Timer t;
    Switch mySwitch;
    SharedPreferences appPrefs;

    String TAG;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto_reminder);

        mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);

        appPrefs = getSharedPreferences("ishaqdev.app.hasanat",MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean setSwitch = appPrefs.getBoolean("switchValue", false);
        if (setSwitch == false){
            mySwitch.setChecked(false);
        }else{
            mySwitch.setChecked(true);
        }


        mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (isChecked) {                    
                    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = appPrefs.edit();
                    prefsEditor.putBoolean("switchValue", true);
                    prefsEditor.commit();

                    tt = new TimerTask() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello Timer !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }      
                    };
                    t = new Timer();

                    t.schedule(tt,0,5000);
                } else {                    
                    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = appPrefs.edit();
                    prefsEditor.putBoolean("switchValue", false);
                    prefsEditor.commit();
                    Log.v(TAG, "After SP");

                    t.cancel();
                    Log.v(TAG, "Final Step");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the stack trace. By guessing, I think that timer is null while you are again opening the activity, so put a null check like this before cancelling the switch

```
if(t != null)
   t.cancel();
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Yes exactly the timer is null and this is the problem, I tried what you suggested and it doesn't perform t.cancel(); so there is no force close message as well as the timer is still working
so, what is the solution?

Comment: @user3104095 first tell me, when u r moving to previous activity, the toast is still showing right ? if yes, then do u want this functionality because when going to previous activity, you may not wat to show the toast ? make me clear on this please.

Comment: Yes, it is still showing and I need it to keep showing until I stop it by switch of the switch key

Comment: @user3104095 then create one java class with static setter and getter method which witll take Timer as it's argument and try to use it.

Comment: Good suggestion, could you please guide me how to implement it?